# HSQL embedded connection

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm trying to connect to my hsqlDb via java script but what ever i add in the db it can't be saved and it doesnt generate any error ! the same when i try to get data from the db and i use Result.next() it generete nulPointerExeption even i have data in my table

```
 Connection con = null; 
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:GestionPiecesDB\\GestionPiece;hsqldb.lock_file=false", "root", "");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBaseTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.print("connected \n");
    Statement stmn;
    try {
        stmn = con.createStatement();
        stmn.executeUpdate("insert into users (nom ,nature , mot_passe ) values ('admin' ,'admin' , 'admin')");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    System.out.print("created \n");

    Statement sn;
    ResultSet r ;
    try {
        sn = con.createStatement();
        r = sn.executeQuery("select * from users");
        if(r.next())
             System.out.print("value \n");
        else
            System.out.print("not value \n");               
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: Did you add hsqldb jar to project?

Comment: yes i did , when i do the getconnection it works but after that every thing executed but no changes in the database

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the exceptions and continuing the program. This means you will not see any errors. Add `throws SQLException` to the method signature and remove all the `try {} catch` blocks for this exception.

Your file path should be absolute. For example:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\GestionPiecesDB\\GestionPiece", "root", "")
```

And you should not disable the lock file for normal use.

Comment: even so it's not working ! can it be because i'm using hsql manger to create the database !!? because when i connect fro a server every thing works fine

Comment: It should work with absolute file path. But `jdbc:hsqldb:file:` connections can be made from only one program at a time. The server mode is better because you can connect from more than one program.